# How can I get partition elimination with a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning, linked-server

I have four identical tables on four servers that I need to query from a fifth.  The fifth server is linked to the other four and has a view created to unify them.

```
-- Servers 1-4
CREATE TABLE Transactions
(
    TxID int not null primary key,
    Description nvarchar(50) not null
);

-- Server 5
CREATE VIEW vwTransactions
AS
SELECT 1 as ServerID, * FROM Server1.DB.dbo.Transactions
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ServerID, * FROM Server2.DB.dbo.Transactions
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as ServerID, * FROM Server3.DB.dbo.Transactions
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as ServerID, * FROM Server4.DB.dbo.Transactions;
```

When I run a query with a constant where clause on the `ServerID` column, I get a nice happy query plan that eliminates three of the partitions.

```
SELECT * FROM vwTransactions WHERE ServerID = 1;
```

[image: happy queryplan that shows a single remote query]

But when I use a parameter, or worse – a join, I get a scan of all four tables.

```
DECLARE @ServerID int = 1;

SELECT *
FROM vwTransactions
WHERE ServerID = @ServerID;
```

[image: sad queryplan showing four remote queries, and concatenation]

I have also tried using inline table valued functions to no avail.

How do I make a view of these tables which can be queried easily?

Comment: @Mitch, is this a distributed partitioned view? With Enterprise or Developer edition, I'd expect a filter with a startup expressions in the plan for dynamic partition elimination.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I don't think so: the source tables have no check constraint.  My partition key is included in the definition of the view itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint to the query will get you the plan you want.

```
DECLARE @ServerID int = 1;

SELECT *
FROM vwTransactions
WHERE ServerID = @ServerID
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The hint allows SQL Server to compile a plan specific to the current value of `@ServerID`. More specifically, it enables the Parameter Embedding Optimization, meaning the query is compiled as if you had written `WHERE ServerID = 1`, allowing partition elimination.

Comment: Is this true anytime a parameter is used on the partition column? This solved my problem that I didn't realize I had until today :/

Comment: @TonyBasallo It's hard to say without more detail about the situation. You should ask a new question and provide important contextual information like table definitions, query, and query plans.

Comment: @tbasallo you got it! I'll be on the lookout for it.