# When do parameters not exclude tables from a partitioned view

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

*It seems that I have some instances where passing a parameter to a partitioned view on the partitioned column still queries all the tables. But now there's more to it...*

I have a four table [partitioned] view on a varchar(2) column. When queried normally, it works as expected. However, when a parameter is used, all 4 tables are checked.   [How can I get partition elimination with a variable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165261/) fixes the issue by using OPTION (RECOMPILE) and solved my issue too. Which I deployed and saw instant perf improvements. I celebrated.

A follow-up question to that question is: Is this ALWAYS the case? If I am using a parameter in SSMS or sp_executesql from APP code, do I need to include OPTION (RECOMPILE) to ensure that the parameter and proper tables eliminated from the view?

**Now it gets a little odd.**

I tried re-running my earlier tests so that I could post the plans and the statistic IO info here for context, but it seems, that now that I've re-deployed code using OPTION(recompile) on the queries, SQL Server knows what it should do :/

The plan still shows 4 tables, but the statistics show just one table read (see screenshots).

Is it possible that the re-compile from the current running queries has given SQL server some needed insight and it now knows what to do? If so, how does one ensure that SQL Server is aware of what to do or do I always use the recompile option?

Some additional context, the SQL is generated from app code and uses sp_executesql and parameters. It looks like this: `exec sp_executesql N'generated sql',N'@0 varchar(4000)',@0='value'`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. I suspect the filters in the screenshot are actually startup expressions so the tables won't be touched at runtime, depending on the variable/parameter value.

Comment: I came here to write that. Look at the Number of Executions on those Scans. They’re probably all zero except for the one that has data you care about. And as Dan says, those Filters will probably show that the partition info is being used to work out not to call the Scan. Remember that plans start on the left, and not everything on the right gets called.

Comment: Yeah - I agree with both of you...but this wasn't the case an hour earlier :( An hour earlier all 4 tables were hit and the query took 2 minutes vs 20 secs. It's only when I did the OPTION(RECOMPILE) that things started working and now I can't get it to misbehave.